# Unable to create a standard StorageClass in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am trying to add a StorageClass to a test K8 cluster to then deploy additional services such as Prometheus. I am running into a problem trying to add a StorageClass of standard to link the pv ad pvc's together. I created a local file called ebs-storage.json with the following:

```
{
  "kind": "StorageClass",
  "apiVersion": "storage.k8s.io/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "standard"
  },
  "provisioner": "kubernetes.io/aws-ebs",
  "parameters": {
    "type": "gp2",
    "zone": "us-west-2a"
  }
}
```

and then I run:

```
kubectl create -f ./ebs-storage.json
```

but this is returning:

```
Error from server: error when creating "./ebs-storage.json": the server could not find the requested resource
```

Running on server version 1.4.6 and client 1.3.4. I know I am missing something obvious but have been unable to figure out what

Answer (score 0):

This ended up being a kubectl version issue. I updated to the latest and was able to create the StorageClass